# MySQL data loading on page scroll through ajax/jquery call doesn't bring correct data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to load mysql database data on page scrolling through ajax/jquery call but it seems correct data is not coming. Actually duplicate data is coming which is already has been fetched and displayed. According to me there is nothing wrong in ajax.php (the file which is responsible to handle ajax request - server side file); only problem in sending the ajax request on page scroll event - id is being passed on window (page) scrolling when a certain condition meets. Below is my code -

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
        {
            var id = $(".item:last").attr("id");
            //alert(id);
            if(id > 1)
            {
                $('#load_more').show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "id="+id,
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html)
                        {
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                            $('#load_more').hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $('#load_more').html('No more posts to show.');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper
{
    width:600px;
    margin:25px auto;
}

.item
{
    border-bottom:1px dotted #555555;
    padding:10px 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

**HTML & PHP**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="postswrapper">
        <?php
        include("includes/db-config.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_comments` ORDER BY `comment_id` DESC LIMIT 10";
        $rs = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
        {
            $comment_id = $row['comment_id'];
            $comment_text = $row['comment_text'];
        ?>
        <div class="item" id="<?php echo $comment_id; ?>">
        <p><span style="color:#FF0000;"><?php echo $comment_id; ?></span>
        <?php echo $comment_text; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>

  <div id="load_more" style="display:none;">
      <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" width="128" height="15" border="0" alt="loading..." />
  </div>

</div>
```

**ajax.php (server-side ajax request handling file)**

```
<?php
include("includes/db-config.php");
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_comments` WHERE `comment_id` < '$id' ORDER BY `comment_id` DESC LIMIT 10";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $comment_id = $row['comment_id'];
        $comment_text = $row['comment_text'];
?>
    <div class="item" id="<?php echo $comment_id; ?>">
    <p><span style="color:#FF0000;"><?php echo $comment_id; ?></span>
    <?php echo $comment_text; ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

**Output -**

[image]

The data should not be published after comment text with id=1 which was first in the table and in fact the last data item to show but you can clearly see in snapshot the data is again fetched and displayed starting from id=6 and then stops at id=1. How to stop this problem?

Comment: You need to prevent multiple ajax requests from being dispatched simultaneously - if you send 3 requests to posts < 3, you'll get those posts 3 times.

Comment: @Sean - you're reading the wrong file

Comment: @SamDufel true, not sure how I missed that.

Comment: @SamDufel i understood your point but how to prevent multiple ajax requests? And I don't think I am reading the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make sure that you're only sending one request at a time is to add a variable which contains the current state of the ajax request / update process.  It's very important that you don't dispatch a second ajax request before the first request finishes processing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var loading = false;    // this variable will prevent duplicate requests
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
        {
            if (loading) {  // if a request is in process, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            loading = true; // set the flag
            var id = $(".item:last").attr("id");
            //alert(id);
            if(id > 1)
            {
                $('#load_more').show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "id="+id,
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html)
                        {
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                            $('#load_more').hide();
                        }
                        loading = false;  // clear the flag
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $('#load_more').html('No more posts to show.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I did the same as you mentioned but it is still not working for me - still showing duplicate data and sending multiple ajax requests again and again. What to do now?